# how to make 2 thermal print work base on pairing devices on android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I'm Setting a new thermal printer("Printer B"). before that, I had already made paired with "Printer A". I already updated the code but still can't print to "Printer A". I want automatically printing whatever I paired my Bluetooth device.

I already Tried to Pair and Unpair, its work. But I don't want that.

```
    try {
        this.mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (this.mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = this.mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {

            for (BluetoothDevice device: paired devices) {

                if (device.getName().equals("Printer A")) {
                    this.mmDevice = device;
                    this.FindOpenBT = true;
                    break;
                }else if(device.getName().equals("Printer B")){
                    mmDevice = device;
                    // myLabel.setText("Paired with "+ device.getName());
                    // Toast toast;
                    //toast = Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Paired with "+ device.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    //toast.show();
                    FindOpenBT = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("Bluetoot_paired", "No Paired: ");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I expected when I change paired to printer A it can print to Printer A..  but when I changed the pair into Printer B it can print to printer B.

when I add that code and paired printer A and printer B, it can only print to the last printer and the device name printer A didn't Exist

Logical Like This:

## Heading

PAIRED_A |DEVICE|  PAIRED_B  |DEVICE  | RESULT

TRUE     | OFF  |    TRUE    | ON     |PRINTING TO B

TRUE     | ON   |   TRUE     | OFF    | System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

TRUE     | ON   | FALSE      | OFF    | PRINTING TO A